# Optimizing Geodesic Distances on a Triangular Mesh

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a convex triangulated mesh. I am able to numerically calculate geodesics between points on the surface; however, I am having trouble tackling the following problem:

Imagine a net being placed over the mesh. The outside boundary of the net coincides with the boundary of the mesh, but the nodes of the net corresponding to the interior of the net are allowed to move freely. I'm interested in finding the configuration that would have the least stress (I know the distances for the at rest state of the net).

Doing this on a smooth surface is simple enough as I could solve for the stresses in terms of the positions of the nodes of the net; however, I don't see a way of calculating the stresses in terms of the position of the net nodes because I don't know that a formula exists for geodesics on a convex triangulated surface.

I'm hoping there is an alternative method to solving this such as a fixed point argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If I am right, as long as a node remains inside a face, the equations are  linear (just as if the node was on a plane). Assuming some node/face correspondence, you can solve for the equilibrium, as if the nodes did belong to the respective planes of support, unconstrained by the face boundaries.

Then for the nodes which are found to lie outside the face, you can project them on the surface and obtain a better face assignment. Hopefully this process might converge to a stable solution.

The picture shows a solution after a first tentative node/face assignment, then a second one after projection/reassignment.

[image]

---

On second thoughts, the problem is even harder as the computation involves geodesic distances between the nodes, which depend on the faces that are traversed. So the domain in which linearity holds when moving a single node is even smaller than a face, it is also limited by "wedges" emanating from the lined nodes and containing no other vertex.

Then you may have to compute the domains where the geodesic distances to a linked neighbor is a linear function of the coordinates and project onto this partition of the surface. Looks like an endeavor.